# Virtualhost on SSL - Can't run Django app in virtualenv after upgrading from httpd 2.2 to 2.4

Tags: python, django, apache, amazon-ec2, virtualhost

I need help in understanding if I have correctly upgraded my website's older config from `httpd-2.2` to `httpd-2.4`. It was hosted on a local server that we have since retired and the entire `/etc/httpd` and `/var/www` directories were copied to an EC2 instance with MySQL installed on the instance itself.

The `Django-1.5` app (yes it needs to be upgraded) runs on the `mod_wsgi` module in daemon mode. I have upgraded the Apache modules and now when I run `python manage.py runserver` after activating my `virtualenv` environment and it gives no errors. But when I navigate to my EC2 public IP address with `https`, it keeps loading the page and times out afterwards. At the moment the `httpd.conf` redirects any port `80` requests to the website domain address, but I'd like to test the deployment on EC2 using bare IP address first before we can update our DNS records.

Another thing I did was to add the public IP address of my EC2 machine to the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` list, along with both `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`.

**Possible SELINUX problem tried but didn't work**

The output of running `httpd` after `runserver` gave the following output:

```
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

I tried `selinux` in both permissive and non-permissive modes and nothing changed.

Please check my config files below and let me know if something doesn't seem right for `httpd-2.4`:

**EDIT** Apache runs fine. I have put an example HTML file in `/var/www/html` and it rendered when I went to the home page on my IP address. It is the Django app that doesn't seem to run, even when I do `python manage.py runserver`

[`/etc/conf/httpd.conf` pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/Q2bbj8jS)

[`/etc/conf.d/vhosts.conf` pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/K5WL6rsf)

[`/etc/conf.d/ssl.conf` pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/XMs3SLXh)

[Django `settings.py` pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/XYbJiPEc)

[Django default `config` file pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/w4xMLsss)

[`manage.py` pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/7535fNMh)

[`wsgi.py` pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/zvenZA5W)

Comment: What user are you using to start your Apache?  To bind on port 80, you need to start it with root (because ports below 1024 require elevated privileges).  Once the first process is started, the children processes will use usre "apache" and group "apache" as specified in your `httpd.conf` file.  The usual way to do this is to run `apachectl` with `sudo`.

Comment: @Nic3500 I am using `ec2-user` to start apache. Because if I run it using root, my activated environment gets deactivated.